# Handling Decimal Places / Avoid Scientific Notation Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have 2 Strings namely

```
string1 = '1000000000.0'
string2 = '1000000000.09'
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal(string1).normalize()
```

gives

```
Decimal('1E+9')
```

and

```
Decimal(string2).normalize()
```

gives

```
Decimal('1000000000.09')
```

Which i actually want like the above.

so how can string1 be as Decimal(1000000000) instead of Decimal('1E+9')
and string2 as Decimal('1000000000.09') which i get in currently.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Functions Do the Trick

```
def DecimalHandler(string):

if re.match('^\d*[.]?\d*$',string):

    Frst = string.split('.')[0]
    try:
        secnd = string.split('.')[1]

        secnd = re.sub('[0]+$','',secnd)
        if secnd != '' :
            secnd = '.'+secnd
        else:
            secnd = secnd

    except IndexError:
        secnd = ''


    OutPut_Str = Frst+secnd
else:
    print("...")
    OutPut_Str = string

return(OutPut_Str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use string formatting. This gives you very close control over how your data is represented - see the [documentation on `str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting) for a full (and a little complex for a beginner) explanation.

To answer your specific request:

```
from decimal import Decimal

string1 = '1000000000.0'
string2 = '1000000000.09'
fstr = '{:10.0f} {:12.2f}'

print(fstr.format(Decimal(string1), Decimal(string2)))
```

You should find the output is

```
1000000000 1000000000.09
```

To make your output easier to understand by humans, you might want to change `fstr` to `'{:10,.0f} {:12,.2f}'` - the commas indicate that the integer part is to be split into comma-separated groups of three, and you should see the output

```
1,000,000,000 1,000,000,000.09
```

Comment: Is there a way instead of Hardcoding Format as .2f,
In Case of '1000000000.9' will give '1000000000.90', But I expect it to be
'1000000000.9'  only, Thanks

Comment: Can't think of a way to do that just with string formatting, but  `'1000000000.90'.rstrip('0')` evaluates to `'1000000000.9'`. Unfortunately that would mean that if there were NO significant decimal places you would see `'1000000000.'`, which may not be what you want. Number formatting is not as easy as it seems ...

Comment: Is there function which could expand  '1E+9' to 1000000000,
This Might do the trick,

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to provide a more comprehensive description of what you are actually trying to do - the easiest way would be a list of numeric values with the corresponding desired representations.

Comment: I Expect the Output to be like ,
10.90 -----> 10.9,
10.0 -------> 10,
10000000000.0 ----> 10000000000,
10000000000.09 -----> 10000000000.09,
10000000000.90 ----->10000000000.9